# How to test Scala files which are in project directory

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using SBT to generate resources in packaging:

```
// content of build.sbt at root of Scala project
resourceGenerators in Compile <+=
  resourceManaged in Compile map { outDir: File =>
    val outFiles = stuffToCreateResources.createResources
    // write files on disk here [...]
    outFiles
  }
```

and I am using some Scala classes (`stuffToCreateResources` here for instance) which are under `./project/*`.

I wrote unit tests for those classes, but I don't know how to test them because the files I want to test are not in src (in other words are not linkable in the tests `src/test/scala`). Any clues?

Comment: AFAIK, everything inside ./project is said to be normal SBT project. You can add a src folder under it and one for tests, or modify the values for `scalaSource in Test` and `scalaSource in Compile`. [Check this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) Well, I tried to explore your clue using `scalaSource in Test` and `unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test` in `build.sbt` file, my `stuffToCreateResources` is recognised, sbt is trying to compile it but I still have a problem because all the external libs I use in my `stuffToCreateResources` are not available and compilation fails...